# Почему оно дозаписывает в файл, а не перезаписывает?

Tags: python

```
alphabet = {'e':False,'i':False,'l':False,'o':False,'u':False,'v':False,'y':False}


f = open('task_masha.txt', 'r+')
asd = f.readline()
asd_split = [asd.split(':')[0], asd.split(':')[1].split('\n')[0]]
alphabet[asd_split[0]] = bool(int(asd_split[1]))
while asd:
    asd = f.readline()
    try:
        asd_split = [asd.split(':')[0], asd.split(':')[1].split('\n')[0]]
    except:
        print('error' + asd)
    print(asd_split)
    print(alphabet)
    alphabet[asd_split[0]] = bool(int(asd_split[1]))

alphabet.update({'e':True})
str_tmp = ''
for i in alphabet:
    str_tmp += i + ':' + str(int(bool(alphabet[i]))) + '\n'
f.write(str_tmp)
f.close()
```

Таким макаром он не перезаписывает файл, а дополняет его, а мне нужно, что бы перезаписывал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = open('task_masha.txt', 'w')
```

'w' – Режим записи, который используется для редактирования и записи новой информации в файл (любые существующие файлы с тем же именем будут удалены при активации этого режима)
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Comment: Ну, так не работает. Он же не сможет читать из файла

Comment: Закройте файл после чтения и затем опять откройте в режиме перезаписи.